# CQRS - How do I handle a user viewing a page or query

Tags: c#, design-patterns, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm using CQRS for an application that I'm building (an online discussion system with complex business logic) and I've reached a part in the implementation that worries me.

How should I handle pageviews? If a user views a thread, I want to track that. Because I want to track that, it follows that I should create a command and an event, and tie this into the aggregate root that is responsible for the object that I'm viewing (for example; UserViewsThread and UserViewedThread, respectively). But this seems widely inefficient - as other than this, there is no reason to hit an aggregate root in many of the use cases of a discussion system (viewing forums/threads). Now that I'm introducing this, I will have an additional command dispatch and event publish on every single view of a page, which is in turn responsible for "spooling up" the thread aggregate, serializing my event, and sending it to my event publisher.

There has to be a better way to do this. I was thinking of perhaps making it so that my  controller object is capable of dispatching events - but by bypassing my aggregate, I can no longer attach behavior to a pageview.

Another possibility is the idea of using this as a way to authenticate my user. The UserViewsThread and UserViewsForum commands will be allowed to throw an authentication exception to let my controller know that the user cannot perform this action. But if these were to be translated into events, and stored in my event store, we're talking about multiple events created *on every page view* - which could very well murder performance (every page view results in a database transaction... ugh) and resource management.

What are your guy's thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Using CQRS doesn't mean that every tiny interaction with the application - especially if i's infrastructure-related - must be passing the command/event chain. Tracking pageviews is a cross-cutting concern that can easily be implemented seperately.

Just **have the queries in the read layer increase a counter** for the respective viewmodels in some table everytime they are called.

Once you start creating comands that mutate state every time a query is called you're tightly coupling read and write again and the whole benefit of Command/Query Separation goes down the drain. You're using CQRS to separate the two concerns in the first place.

Comment: It's worth to mention, that aggregate root may have serious problems with concurrency if every page view will generate an event. OP should use statsd for tracking purposes, as it's very fast - you can process your page views behind-the-scenes and update the domain model based on the collected data.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture tracking information in a session and send it to the server once in a while.

Additionally, why do you think you really need to have an AR with event store to track this information? I would've aggregated this information in some state-based storage.

Comment: Well, what users view could be very significant in reporting. If my reporting infrastructure uses the event store to reply events into my read model, then I'll be able to construct more granular reports based off of user views of specific queries.

Comment: Personally I prefer just to use Google analytics for tracking visits.

Answer (score 1):

We were doing almost the same as this. But it doesn't feel right to track everything like this, your reads should be fast and not required to do any writes.

We ended up adding a tracking object to all our events, but I don't think I would do that again. I would look into writing some javascript just like google analytics and create a separate command from the front-end.

Also I would separate out your tracking queue and your normal queue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a web app so I'd create an attribute (asp.net mvc/WebApi) wich will handle the page views. Of course the attribute would only call an INFRASTRUCTURE service (as I think that tracking stats is not part of the domain) which will just update the page views in the storage. Simply put, the service calls a Dao which updates the persistence (update Posts set pageviews=pageviews+1).

Of course the attribute can just send async a command to update page views which will be executed in the background so the 'writes' won't actually interfere with the reads.

If your app has/will have lots of traffic then I'd suggest the following persistence strategy: Have a table PageViews(PageId,ViewsNumber,TimeStamp) where you just append a row for every page view. Then every X minutes, have a background service which will do a Sum(ViewsNumber) GroupBy(PageId) where TimeStamp> oldTimestamp. You won't have stats at the milisecond but they will be updated often enough and the app will stay responsive.

I don't consider this concern part of any domain outside the case you're building an Analytics system, so you don't need AR, DDD or Event sourcing. For your case, the page stats are information attached to the page and not part of a page. They are considered together only in the read model where you actually display them in the same view.